# How to find if a word occurs twice, ad a number occurs once in a tuple

Tags: python

```py
data = ((45, 'foot'), (21, 'basket'), (10, 'hand'), (24, 'foot'), (21, 'hand'))

def unique_data_items(data): 
  input data is made of ((int, string), (int, string), ...) 
  unique_nums = () #initialising the tuple 
  unique_words = () 
  Add code to fill the tuples unique_nums and unique_words with  
  numbers and words that are unique
  returns the pair (tuple) of the numbers of unique numbers and   
  words
```

How do i complete the code, so it can return the word which occurs once, and the number which occurs twice, i have attempted it but cannot figure out how to this, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your post including using code blocks so it is easier for people to read. Also, please provide your attempt and why it didn't work so we can address the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for x,y in data:
    if y not in d:
        d[y] = x
    else:
        d[y] += x
unique = tuple(d.items())
```

I think is what you want the output of this code is:

```
(('foot', 69), ('basket', 21), ('hand', 31))
```

Comment: This looks like a good use case for a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).